# How to remove g++

Tags: fonts, g++, removing

I recently installed the g++ complier for c++ coding somehow its messing with my fonts and only a restart fixes the issue.
Is there any way to uninstall g++?and is that safe to do?

Comment: how can g++ mess with your fonts?

Comment: no idea right after install my fonts started getting screwy. forgive me if I’m a noob i just want to uninstall it

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge g++` or `sudo apt-get autoremove g++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to uninstall `g++` only do the following in terminal,

```
sudo apt-get remove g++
```

If you have to remove it's dependencies also try,

```
sudo apt-get purge g++
```

If you want to delete g++ configuration also, try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge g++
```

else you can do,

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove g++
```

Comment: thank you it worked! How do I confirm if its removed?

Comment: `g++ -v` is the command to check version.. it may help you.. check it..